# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -1 when trying to remove item

Tags: android

I want to be able to click on an item and then go through the options menu to my "remove" function to remove it from the ArrayList, i've been getting an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** though.

Here is code that selects the item in the "onCreate" method.

```
 timetableListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
 timetableListView.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
 timetableListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            timetableListView.setSelection(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Here is the options menu method

```
   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    int index = timetableListView.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case (Remove_Item): {
            if (addingNew) {
                cancelAdd();
            } else {
                removeItem(index);
            }
            return true;
        }
        case (Add_New_Item): {
            addNewItem();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**The removeItem method**

```
    private void removeItem(int _index) {

    timetableItemsList.remove(_index);
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I'm not sure how to get the position of the item and assign it to the "int index" i've declared in the options menu method

Answer (score 0):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will occur if you try to get or remove an item from collection which is not there.say your arraylist size is  9 and you tried to remove 10th item. 
Also use onItemselected Listener of Listview to get the selected item from Listview